# java - How to get the total weeks and days

Tags: java, calendar

```
System.out.println(
  String.format(
     "You are %s weeks, and %s days pregnant", weeks , days ));
```

Comment: what is this?                             ...

Comment: Get total weeks and days from when?

Comment: you gotta define `String weeks, days` and assign some value to it before this line.

Comment: Do you want us to create you an application. This is more like logic than a question

Comment: @bms that's obvious. ;p (pun intended)

Comment: the first input is the last date where the patient Last mens peroid(LMP)

Comment: @Nishant, +1 I see what you did there

Comment: just like looking for weeks and days in two months

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for days difference between two date -

```
public int daysBetween(Date d1, Date d2){
 return (int)( (d2.getTime() - d1.getTime()) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
 }
```

week -

```
public int weeksBetween(Date d1, Date d2){
 return (int)( (d2.getTime() - d1.getTime()) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7));
 }
```

Comment: just like looking for weeks and days in nine months

Comment: code has been updated. you can pass any date two date and get the days and weeks

Answer (score 0):

use **java.util.Calendar**

```
t.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)     // --- int value of the day of the month (1-31)



t.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)      // --- int value of the day of the week (0-6)
```

Comment: **difference** is the keyword here.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this

```
int num ; // no. of days
int weeks ; // no of weeks
//initialise num 
weeks = num/7;
days = num % 7;
System.format("no of weeks"+weeks+"no of days"+days);
```

Comment: ya,, but this will calculate by the last date and the current date..

Comment: can u be more specific with ur use-case